# Sum of value taking distinct ID and latest date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My table goes like

```
ID       Date        Value

ID1     01.01.2022    10

ID1     01.02.2022    10

ID1     01.03.2022    20

ID1     01.04.2022    30

ID2     01.01.2022    20
```

Expected result - 50 (Value 30 for ID1 with date 1.04.2022 + Value 20 from ID2)

I know I can get such table (with only ID1 last date and ID2 last date) using:

```
SELECT ID, VALUE, DATE FROM ( 
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE ASC)
 AS ROWNUM 
FROM "Table") X 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

but dont now how to SUM (Value) in this. Could you help me?

Comment: I think your query will not return 30 for ID1 because your row_number is ordered by date ascending, so your 1st row for ID1 will be *ID1     01.01.2022    10*. If you want 30 you should order it by date descending in that case or you can use max value for each ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You should use `ROW_NUMBER` in a subquery to identify the latest row for each `ID` value.  Then sum the value over that intermediate table.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT SUM(Value) AS Total
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```